# How to maintain leading zeros within an Excel file format

Tags: excel, ms-office, leading-zero

I have tried using csv and txt format but each of them pose their own problem.

With the csv format I have found that it is possible to add a tab character before the number and that will preserve the leading zeros, but when the user adds characters to the front of the number, there will be a space in the middle of the number.

With the txt format the only way to preserve the leading zeros is to import the txt file into Excel and dictate each column that has numbers in it to be cast as text cells. Since a client could be opening this file, those instructions are too difficult to rely on a client not to mess up.

Basically what I need is a file format or a way to edit a csv that allows it to maintain leading zeros when it is opened into Excel, but to also be editable without losing the integrity of the number and not show any special characters when editing the cell. Please let me know any areas that need clarification as this is an oddly specific problem.

Comment: I think you need to use a more sophisticated spreadsheet file format that supports formatting data, like XLSX or XLS.  Are you quoting the values in your CSV?  This might help if you are not doing it already.

Comment: Yeah I am quoting them but then when I go to edit them in Excel, it shows the quotes. And if a client deletes one on accident, it could ruin everything. The problem with XLSX and XLS is that we have a framework that would require a massive overhaul to edit that file format. Mainly what I'm looking for is a file format that I can edit the raw text in such a way that it maintains leading zeros without quotes or tabs

Comment: Why not format the numbers after they're imported? Highlight a cell/range to format and right-click then select Format Cells. In the Number format select the Custom item at the bottom of the list, then in the Type entry area type in "000000000". That will format any number with leading zeros.

Comment: That's the problem. The end user is opening it and I cannot put any of the process on them. That's the solution I've been trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're importing text or CSV I assume that you're using the "get data from text" tool.  The way to maintain the leading zeros is to set the imported field to be "text" instead of "general" during step 3 of the import.

If you need to add leading zeroes back in to a specified length you can also use `Right(Concatenate("00...00",text cell),desired length of field)`.

Comment: This would work if it was something I could add to the CSV. The solution needs to be reached from the raw file like a csv or txt file. The best solution thus far is to select text for the field with leading zeros but ideally there would be no interaction once the file is opened.

Comment: unfortunately with CSVs and TXT files, there is no way to keep any sort of formatting in place if the file is being directly edited in a text editor.  You could write a VBA script to load and correct the files, then export them back into the text format, but keeping any kind of field formatting within the text file is impossible.